# Inconveniente con conexión a base de datos Mysql WorkBench desde Php y Jsp

Tags: php, java, jsp, mysql-workbench

Cordial saludo equipo, agradezco por favor su amable colaboración con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta al conectar una aplicación desarrollada en Jsp y java con una base de datos Mysql WorkBench, la aplicación esta desarrollada en el IDE Netbeans:

El código que tengo de un archivo que se llama Conexión.java es el siguiente:
package Control;     //Este es el paquete en donde se encuentra este archivo

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {
    private static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String USUARIO = "root";
    private static String PASSWORD = "";
    private static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alumnotas";

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en el driver" + e);

        }

    }

   public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, PASSWORD);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion exitosa");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la Conexion" + e);
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Vale mencionar que dentro de las librerías tengo el MYSQL JDBC Driver -mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar y el mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar

Estoy utilizando el servidor Wampserver

La configuración de la base de datos es la siguiente:
El nombre es Conexion , el usuario es root y el localhost es 3306

Al ejecutar el archivo Conexión.java, me aparece lo siguiente:
Class “Conexion” neither has a main method nor is it a servlet specified in web.xml.
Googleando he hecho reajustes que se me indican como cambiar el .jar y modificar los puertos, pero desafortunadamente al volver a ejecutar el archivo  Conexión.java me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.
Inconveniente de conexión pero en php:

Al intentar realizar la conexión pero en php, con el siguiente código

```
<?php

$host = "localhost:3306";  //Valor de nuestra BD o sino 127.0.0.1:3307
$basededatos = "alumnotas"; //AlumnoNotas
$usuariodb = "root";
$clavedb = ""; //Cali79628*
//Lista de Tablas
$tabla_db1 = "alumnos";
$tabla_db2 = "notas";

error_reporting(0);

$conexion = new mysqli($host, $usuariodb, $clavedb, $basededatos);
echo "Conexion exitosa ";
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "Sitio experimenta fallos ";
    exit();
}
?>
```

me aparece lo siguiente
Conexión exitosa Sitio experimenta fallos
Es decir me aparece tanto que he hecho la conexión así como que no la hecho, algo totalmente ilógico.

Muchas gracias por su colaboración
Atentamente
Hernán Martínez

Comment: estudia esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/36861329/4717133 y avisa si te sirve. saludos.

Comment: Buenas. Una pregunta por post, por favor. Aquí tienes dos preguntas distintas, cada una con un lenguaje de programación distinto. Divídela en dos.

Comment: La clase conexión no tiene un `main`, por lo tanto, no puedes ejecutarla sin indicar el metodo que hace de `main`. Esta clase tampoco la pudes ejecutar  desde el servidor directamente porque no es una clase invocable desde el servidor. Por otro lado, tienes un `showMessageDialog` que sería solo para la ejecución desde escritorio.

Comment: En PHP te salen los dos mensajes porque preguntas connect_errno sin condición alguna y por lo tanto siempre regresará verdadero

Comment: En fase de desarrollo puedes mostrar en pantalla el motivo del error, por ejemplo, dentro del bloque `if` puedes poner esto: `echo  $conexion->connect_error;` Convendría que aprendas a revisar los logs de errores para depurar el código con mayor rapidez.